# Getting rid of activation lock on iPad

Tags: ipad

I got my deceased aunt's iPad and no one can remember security answers to reset password and the email used to set up is no longer valid and house has been sold so a password reset can not be sent to me.

Comment: You need to request access to her account to proceed https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208510 This article includes all the steps needed to retrieve any data, delete any data, and disconnect the ipad

Comment: Voting to re-open since this is not the same question. The steps when you've purchased a device are different than when the owner is deceased.